# C# Exportación de un datagridview a Excel con formato?

Tags: c#

Con el siguiente código puedo exportar sin problemas un datagridview  pero sin algún formato, estilo de letra, etc. ¿Que me hace falta para lograr esto?

Este código esta creado en una clase.

---

```
class Exportar2
    {
        public void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
        {
        try
            {
                SaveFileDialog archivo = new SaveFileDialog();
                archivo.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
                archivo.FileName = "Registro de produccion " + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '-');
                if (archivo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libroDeTrabajo;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hojaDeTrabajo;
                    aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    libroDeTrabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
                    hojaDeTrabajo = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libroDeTrabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "A"] = grd.Columns[0].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "B"] = grd.Columns[1].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "C"] = grd.Columns[2].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "D"] = grd.Columns[3].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "E"] = grd.Columns[4].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "F"] = grd.Columns[5].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "G"] = grd.Columns[6].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "H"] = grd.Columns[7].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "I"] = grd.Columns[8].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "J"] = grd.Columns[9].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "K"] = grd.Columns[10].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "l"] = grd.Columns[11].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "M"] = grd.Columns[12].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "M"] = grd.Columns[13].HeaderText;
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[1, "M"] = grd.Columns[14].HeaderText;

                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[1].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[2].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[3].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[4].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[5].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[6].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[7].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[8].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[9].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[10].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[11].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[12].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[13].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Columns[14].AutoFit();
                    hojaDeTrabajo.Name = "Exportacion";
                    //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo
                    for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                            {
                                hojaDeTrabajo.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    libroDeTrabajo.SaveAs(archivo.FileName,
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
                    libroDeTrabajo.Close(true);
                    aplicacion.Quit();
                    MessageBox.Show("Registro de produccion Exportado a Excel", "AMMNSA");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al exportar la informacion debido a: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }***
```

Después lo mando llamar con el botón.

```
Exportar2 exp = new Exportar2();
            exp.ExportarDataGridViewExcel(dataGridView1);
```

Comment: ¿Con formato o sin formato?

Comment: Es importante realices el [tour] como se ha sugerido anteriormente y con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, tu pregunta es confusa, el titulo no tiene relación con el contenido como comenta NaCL, saludos!

Comment: A continuación te presento varios link que pueden ayudarte: [La respuesta podría estar aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39314154/8933039) , [este es otro link de interes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33146802/8933039), ademas [este otro link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406704/Export-DataTable-to-Excel-with-Formatting-in-Cshar), creo que pueden ayudarte en lo que necesitas. (Los Link's están en inglés, pero puedes Traducir la Página con GoogleTranslate fácilmente).

Comment: el codigo esta bien pero me quita un registro, por ejemplo, si tengo 5 registros en la base de datos, en excel solo me muestra 4